# 301 rederection in Telegram groups

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Is there a way to create a new group link and make this link redirects to another group?

Like a 301 redirection in websites.

Answer (score 0):

No. It would be great feature.
But I haven't seen anything like you described in documentation, API refs or any groups I used before.